# Connecting my domain name to my droplet

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address, dns-zone

I setup an Apache static website on a DigitalOcean droplet.

The company that hosts my domain name (webhostingpad) provides an "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" which I used to setup a (redirect/forward?) to my droplet.

My domain name is "icecoldnugrape.com".

In the "Zone File Records" section, with TTL=7200, Class=IN, and Type=A, I pointed "icecoldnugrape.com." to the IP address of my droplet. I did this a few months ago.

When I visit my domain name in the url I get forwarded correctly to what my droplet's Apache server is serving, but the IP address of the droplet has taken over the browser's URL bar, rather than my domain name.

**How do I keep my domain-name in the url bar of the browser?**

[image]

Comment: Nice question  +1   Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: Sending GET for `http://icecoldnugrape.com` or `http://www.(same)` to your host (which does resolve to 107.170.41.208) returns a 302 redirect (which any normal browser follows) to `http://107.170.41.208/jrrecordings` from a server that identifies as `Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)`. That sounds like your server. Check your redirect and/or rewrite with [R] rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out (seems obvious now) that in my `index.php` which is the entry point for incoming requests to my Apache server I was doing:

```
<?php header('Location: http://107.170.41.208/jrrecordings/'); ?>
```

When I should have had:

```
<?php header('Location: http://icecoldnugrape.com/jrrecordings/'); ?>
```

So, my DNS settings were not the issue, and this was just user error.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will want to do is make sure you set the name servers within your domain's host settings to:

NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM

NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM

NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM

Also make sure you add the domain to your Digital Ocean's droplet by logging in choosing your droplet and hitting Networking at top, you will see a section that says domains where you can add domain. Here is how I set mine up:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**set an 'A Record' for your WWW entry**

Once you have that complete use a CNAME for your domain name entry rather than binding the CNAME to an IP, bind it to a name.

Comment: I changed the "www" entry to: `www.icecoldnugrape.com. 7200 IN A 107.170.41.208`, but kind of struggling with the second task to do. After work will google up on differences between "CNAME" and "A Record"